# 3D Probability distribution

Tags: graphics3d

I have a structure like this:

```
R[i_, j_] := ({26.82 Cos[(2 Pi)/30.0 i], 26.82 Sin[(2 Pi)/30.0 i], 
   10 j})

 Graphics3D[
 Map[{Red, Sphere[#, 2]} &, 
  Chop@Flatten[Table[R[i, j], {i, 1, 30}, {j, 1, 10}], 1]]]
```

[image]

Each sphere could be considered an atom. To each atom a number is assigned. These numbers show a probability distribution. I want the color of each atom to be proportional to this probability. The higher probability the brighter color. How can I color these spheres according to this probability distribution?
As an example here is one distribution:

```
Table[1/84  Exp[-i*i*1.0/9000], {i, 1, 300}];
```

Comment: What is the reason for downvote? At least tell me to correct the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your probabilities a bit to make them better match your sphere specification, and to get a more interesting color pattern, but you'll get the idea:

```
probs = Table[1/84 Exp[-i*j*1.0/9000], {i, 1, 30}, {j, 1, 10}];
minprob = Min@probs;
maxprob = Max@probs;
probsScaled = Rescale[probs, {minprob, maxprob}, {0, 1}];
colors = Map[ColorData["DarkRainbow"], probsScaled, {2}];

Graphics3D[Table[{colors[[i, j]], Sphere[R[i, j], 2]}, {i, 1, 30}, {j, 1, 10}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Rescale! Does a good work, thanks for the call attention to it!

Answer (score 3):

```
colors = Hue[100 #] & /@ Table[1/84 Exp[-i*i*1.0/9000], {i, 1, 300}];
spheres = Sphere[#, 2] & /@ Chop[Flatten[Table[R[i, j], {i, 1, 30}, {j, 1, 10}], 1]];
Graphics3D[Thread[{colors, spheres}]]
```

[image]